# C++, cast constructor, "no operator "=" matches these operands

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Hello i got a little problem with my C++ project.

First of all i got the class:

```
class base
{
protected:
    int R, G, B;
public:
    base();
    ~base();
};
```

and the second class:

```
class superBase :
    public base
{
public:
    superBase(){R=0; G=0; B=0};
    ~superBase();
};
```

and the last class which contains the matrix of base class'es:

```
class gameTable : public gameGraphics
{
private:
    base** table;
public:
    gameTable();
    ~gameTable();
}
```

When i construct the gameTable class i construct 64 base objects with RANDOM R, G, B values from 0 to 255.

So when the programs goes on, some of mine elemntes in table 'evolves' and becomes superBase's. So here is my problem i don't know how to do that thing. I tried this,

which seems to not working properly.

```
        superBase newBase;
        table[column][row].~base();
        table[column][row] = newBase;
```

and the other version:

```
    table[column][row].~base();
    table[column][row] = new superBase;
```

My question is how to evolve one element of the table to the superBase class element. As i know it can use the same pointer as base class element.

Greetings and thanks for help!

Comment: where is the definition of `table` ?

Comment: `new T` returns  a pointer. Your "2D array" doesn't hold pointers. Also, don't call the destructors like that.

Comment: `table[column][row].~base();` <-- don't call destructors like this. If you are allocating with `new`, you need to `delete`. But you should instead use smart pointers and vectors where possible.

Answer (score 1):

> “no operator ”=" matches these operands

Here:

```
table[column][row] = new superBase;
```

`table[a][b]` is a `base` lvalue reference. You are passing it the result of a call to `new`. This returns  pointer to `superBase`. That assignment can't work. This one would compile

```
table[column][row] = superBase();
```

but you would get [*object slicing*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c). You need to find a way to store (smart) pointers to the base type.

Besides that, your base class needs a virtual destructor. And you shouldn't be calling the destructors directly.